# MySQL - Data entry

Tags: mysql, database, insert, enterprise, insertion

I have just finished programming a company database in MySQL (I am a student, I am gaining experience). I have to do the data entry but the amount of data to insert is immense. Is there a way to quickly insert large amounts of data without going through Excel?

Best regards.

Comment: In which format is the data available with you ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I get data in Excel, but there is no standard data organization. Each company sends its own excel document with a different format.

Answer (score 0):

I use SQLYog , which is free tool on the internet.
You can use this tool to work on MySQL and you won't have to open your Workbench again.
It has a WIDE variety of functions including user-level-access and IMPORTING DATA IN A TABLE VIA CSV.

U need to ensure your data file is saved as .csv and it DOESN'T contain the header row, also you must have a table having the EXACT number of columns (of course), you can insert your entire data (even VERY VERY large data) into your table.

Also while inserting you need to check on "Insert Excel-friendly values", and BOOM....you are done !! :D

please feel free to connect whenever you encounter any issue, it looks hard the first time, then it's VERY VERY easy.